# Solving for a variable in an inverse function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

I was asked to solve this formula for $R_2$:

> $$\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3}$$

So I did the following:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{R_2} &= \frac{1}{R} - \frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_3} \\[8pt]
 &= \frac{R_1R_3-RR_3-RR_1}{RR_1R_3}
\end{align*}
Then I took the inverse of both sides to get:
$$R_2 = \frac{RR_1R_3}{R_1R_3-RR_3-RR_1}$$

It seems to be correct but I don't know. So is it?

Comment: beware the sign! you have a lot of minus that misteriously disappeared

Comment: I retract my previous comment. Exodd is on the money.

Comment: I think you have a couple of plus signs where you need minus signs but besides that you're ok.

Comment: Oh my god! Thanks guys I've fixed my signs.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is $100\%$ correct.